# ggplot - facet wrap - adjusting scale to show apparent differences between values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like below:

```
text <- "
brand   a   b   c   d   e   f
nissan  99.21   99.78   6496    1.28    216 0.63
toyota  99.03   99.78   7652    1.39    205 0.60
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep="\t", header = T)
```

I'm trying to get all the variables for the two groups plotted in a single ggplot using `face_wrap`as below:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(melt(df, id = "brand")) + 
  aes(brand, value, fill = brand) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position='dodge') +
  geom_text(data=melt(df, id = "brand"), angle = 0, 
               aes(brand, value,
                   label = ifelse(value > 100, round(value, 0), value) ) ) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
    theme(
      legend.position = "top",
      strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank()
      )
```

It works well except for one thing. The apparent differences between the group for value of a variable is not coming out very well visually. For example for variable `a` I want the height of the bars to be such that it is clear which is the higher one in an easier fashion. How do I get the height difference between such close values to be larger?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a bar plot? By default these start at the origin, so differences between large numbers become relatively indistinguishable. If the purpose is to illustrate the difference (& since you are using free y scales anyway), why not do away with the bars & draw a line between Nissan & Toyota in each facet?

Comment: I need to use bar plot - is there a way to specify to dynamically adjust the origins based on the y values ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

(I wasn't planning to return to this, since I think all the answers are really on the same side. But it kept popping up on my feed, until I finally thought of an angle that hasn't been mentioned yet.)

The only way I can think of that somewhat justifies using bars in this context is to make it *very* clear that the bar heights represent **rank**, not **value**:

```
df2 <- melt(df, id = "brand") %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(value))

> df2
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups: variable [6]
   brand  variable    value  rank
   <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 nissan a          99.2    2.00
 2 toyota a          99.0    1.00
 3 nissan b          99.8    1.50
 4 toyota b          99.8    1.50
 5 nissan c        6496      1.00
 6 toyota c        7652      2.00
 7 nissan d           1.28   1.00
 8 toyota d           1.39   2.00
 9 nissan e         216      2.00
10 toyota e         205      1.00
11 nissan f           0.630  2.00
12 toyota f           0.600  1.00
```

Use rank for the y-values, and everything else can flow naturally without bringing in `geom_rect()` & so on:

```
ggplot(df2,
       aes(x = brand, y = rank, fill = brand,
           label = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(vjust = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  theme(
    legend.position="top",
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
    axis.text=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  )
```

(Plot image not included. It's essentially the same chart as below, except for the y-axis title being "rank" now.)

Is the result still chart junk? I'd say yes, but if you absolutely have to show arbitrary bars to others, tell them the height is based on rank, and it should make a *bit* more sense.

**Original answer below**

If you really need to use a bar plot, you can use `geom_rect` & manually define a different ymin for each facet.

Modify dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- melt(df, id = "brand") %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(ymax = value, 
         ymin = ifelse(diff(value) == 0, 0,
                       min(value) - (max(value) - min(value)) / 2),
         yblank = ifelse(diff(value) == 0, value * 2,
                         max(value) + (max(value) - min(value)) / 2),
         x = as.integer(brand),
         xmin = x - 0.4,
         xmax = x + 0.4,
         label = ifelse(value > 100, round(value, 0), value)) %>%
  ungroup()

> df2
# A tibble: 12 x 10
   brand  variable    value     ymax     ymin   yblank     x  xmin  xmax    label
   <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 nissan a          99.2     99.2     98.9     99.3       1 0.600  1.40   99.2  
 2 toyota a          99.0     99.0     98.9     99.3       2 1.60   2.40   99.0  
 3 nissan b          99.8     99.8      0      200         1 0.600  1.40   99.8  
 4 toyota b          99.8     99.8      0      200         2 1.60   2.40   99.8  
 5 nissan c        6496     6496     5918     8230         1 0.600  1.40 6496    
 6 toyota c        7652     7652     5918     8230         2 1.60   2.40 7652    
 7 nissan d           1.28     1.28     1.23     1.44      1 0.600  1.40    1.28 
 8 toyota d           1.39     1.39     1.23     1.44      2 1.60   2.40    1.39 
 9 nissan e         216      216      200      222         1 0.600  1.40  216    
10 toyota e         205      205      200      222         2 1.60   2.40  205    
11 nissan f           0.630    0.630    0.585    0.645     1 0.600  1.40    0.630
12 toyota f           0.600    0.600    0.585    0.645     2 1.60   2.40    0.600
```

This creates bars such that the shorter bar in each facet occupies one quarter of the facet's height, while the taller bar occupies three quarters. If the two bars are exactly the same height, they both occupy half the facet's height. If you want to tweak the appearance, just change ymin / yblank.

Plot:

```
ggplot(df2,
       aes(x = x, y = ymax, fill = brand)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
                ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), 
            vjust = -1) + # position labels slightly above top of each bar
  geom_blank(aes(y = yblank)) +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  theme(
    legend.position="top",
    strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
    axis.text=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank()
  )
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I upvoted because it does answer the question as posed, but I detest the result. Bars should never start at arbitrary y values.

Comment: @ClausWilke I appreciate the distinction, & I agree. It's not my favourite type of visualization, either.

Comment: As Z.Lin and @Clause Wilke have very clearly stated, it is not good practice to adjust the start point of columns in a barplot as the relative length of bars is no longer proportionate to the values plotted, and paired comparisons are rendered meaningless. Those who read it will struggle to reconcile the visual impression of the bars with the numbers annotated. It could be considered to be an intentionally biased and misleading form of presentation - and as Claus stated clearly in his solution it is chart junk at best.

Answer (score 15):

I'm sure people will happily tell you how to hack ggplot2 so you can have bars start at an arbitrary y value. **However, you need to be aware that the result will be a meaningless junk chart,** in particular if you strip the y axis of axis ticks. I would recommend reading this blog post on the [principle of proportional ink.](http://callingbullshit.org/tools/tools_proportional_ink.html)

One solution that you could pursue is to plot bars that represent the ratio of the two variables, like so:

```
text <- "
brand   a   b   c   d   e   f
nissan  99.21   99.78   6496    1.28    216 0.63
toyota  99.03   99.78   7652    1.39    205 0.60
"

df_wide <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep="\t", header = T)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_long <- gather(df_wide, variable, value, -brand) %>%
  spread(brand, value) %>%
  mutate(ratio = nissan/toyota,
         label = paste(signif(nissan, 3), signif(toyota, 3), sep = " / "),
         vjust = ifelse(ratio >= 1, -.5, 1.5)) %>%
  mutate(ratio = ifelse(ratio == 1, 1.001, ratio))

ggplot(df_long, aes(variable, ratio, fill = (ratio>=1))) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label, vjust = vjust)) +
  scale_y_log10(name = "ratio Nissan / Toyota",
                breaks = c(.85, .9, .95, 1, 1.05, 1.1),
                expand = c(.15, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired", guide = "none")
```

[image]

The result is only a single bar per pairing, but the bar height accurately reflects the relative magnitude of the two variables. And you don't seem to be interested in the absolute magnitude anyways, since you're using free y axis scaling in your original `facet_wrap()` command.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the answers and comments that it is not a good idea to manipulate the relative bar length. If you just want to show which bar is higher in current plot, you can use another aesthetic to highlight it, for example put the higher bar in a box like the plot below.

[image]

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(RColorBrewer)

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)


# add a winner column to mark the winner in red
aaa <- melt(df, id = "brand") %>%
    setDT() %>%
    .[, winner := ifelse(value > mean(value), "red", "NA"), by = variable]

# plot and show the higher bar in read box
ggplot(aaa, aes(brand, value, fill = brand)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(color = winner), stat = "identity", position='dodge') +
    geom_text(data=melt(df, id = "brand"), angle = 0, 
              aes(brand, value,
                  label = ifelse(value > 100, round(value, 0), value) ) ) +
    facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
    scale_color_identity() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "top",
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's misleading to start scales at arbitrary y values as many on this thread have pointed out.

One answer that hasn't been considered is to put the scales on an **log scale** with `scale_y_log10()`, and combine with `geom_text` labels to show differences between facetted groups.

## data

```
df <- data_frame(
  pair = letters[1:6] %>% rep(2),
  brand = c("nissan", "toyota") %>% rep(each = 6),
  value = c(99.21, 99.78, 6496, 1.28, 216, 0.63, 
            99.03, 99.78, 7652, 1.39, 205, 0.60)
)
```

## plot

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = brand, y = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = brand)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = -1) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~pair) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]